# How to declare function which returns type of function which is passed as an argument in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class method function which is a function for decoration of some function. I need to declare returning value of this function as "Return value is a return value of function which is provided as a parameter"

How can I do it to save typization?

```js
  function operation(): number {
    return 2
  }

  const a = ManagerOfOperations.execute(operation)
```

```js
  public execute(operationBodyFunction: () => unknown): ReturnType<typeof operationBodyFunction> {
    let functionResult
    try {
      functionResult = operationBodyFunction()
    } catch (error) {
      const operationError: OperationError = {
        originalError: error,
        managerName: this.name,
      }
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(snapError))
    }

    return functionResult
  }
```

When I use method from outside, I always have return value of execute method as unknow, but, for example, in this case, I expect number

I tried to use generics here, but my attempts have failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using generics in 3 simple steps:

1. Add `<T>` after the function name(you can change `T` to whatever name you want to)
2. State that the return type of the parameter is of type `T`
3. State that the return type of the function is of type `T`

```
public execute<T>(operationBodyFunction: () => T): T {
    return operationBodyFunction();
}
```

You can call the function like this `execute(() => 0)`, in this example your IDE should realize that `T` is of type number.
You can also state the type using `execute<{}>(() => ({}))`.

JSDoc would look like this:

```
/**
 * @param {() => T} operationBodyFunction
 * @template {T}
 * @returns {T}
 */
function execute<T>(operationBodyFunction: () => T): T;
```